# How do you read poison messages from the WebSphere SI Bus exception queue using JMS

Tags: jms, websphere, sibus

As the title of the question states, how can I read poison messages from the WebSphere SI Bus exception queue using JMS?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SIB Exception Destination is a classic Queue so you can access it as you would access a JMS Queue.
In WAS there are two ways to do this:

1. Using **JNDI lookup**

This is the classic way to read from JMS resource. You only need to create a Queue Resource (from WAS console `> Resources > JMS > Queue > New`) using the Exception Destination as your "Queue Name". You then lookup the Destination using the JNDI name you set in your Queue Resource above.

2. Directly using the `com.ibm.websphere.sib` package ([read more here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tmj_pgmng.html)) where destination URL is something like `queue://_SYSTEM.Exception.Destination.yourwasnode.yourserver-yourSIB`

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the quick reply, just what we were looking for.